# How do I group by using anonymous type

Tags: c#, linq, anonymous-types

I am getting a result set from a linq query and then using group by to group on two fields:

```
var dataElements = dataElements.GetAll();

var dataItems = dataElements.Where(el => el.Field1 == "DATE")
     .GroupBy(x => new { x.Field2, x.Field3})
     .ToList();

//why can't I do this:
foreach (var element in dataItems)
{
    Console.WriteLine(element.Field2)
}
```

I get the following error:

> Severity  Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
>   Error CS1061  'IGrouping<, dataElements>' does not contain a definition for 'Field2'
>   and no accessible extension method 'Field2' accepting a first
>   argument of type 'IGrouping<, dataElements>' could be found (are you missing a using
>   directive or an assembly
>   reference?)   App.Program C:.....cs  498 Active

Comment: The title doesn't reflect the actual question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to select fields before access them:

```
var dataItems = dataElements.Where(el => el.Field1 == "DATE")
 .GroupBy(x => new { x.Field2, x.Field3})
 .Select(x=>new {Field2=x.FirstOrDefault().Field2})
 .ToList();
```

now you can access *Field2* :

```
foreach (var element in dataItems)
{
  Console.WriteLine(element.Field2)
}
```

---

Alternatively you can do it in your for loop:

```
foreach (var group in dataItems)
{
  foreach(var item in group)
     Console.WriteLine(item.Field2);
}
```

Comment: your code is missing .Select . sql equivalent after grouping

Comment: after grouping there is a select which part is missing?

Comment: .GroupBy().Select()

Comment: I'm not getting what you talking about can you add another answer

Comment: I can't imagine that either of these options are what the OP wants. Why do a `GroupBy` if he's ignoring the elements or doing a `.SelectMany` afterwards?

Comment: Right, it's more likely he wants list of Field2 values for each group(not all elements) after grouping by two fileds, same as your answer.

Answer (score 3):

You need to select the `Key` first before `Field2`. Try this:

```
foreach (var element in dataItems)
{
    Console.WriteLine(element.Key.Field2)
}
```

Answer (score 2):

As it says group doesn't know what `Field2` is so you need to grab each element of the group. Try this:

```
foreach (var group in dataItems) 
{ 
    foreach(var element in group)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(element.Field2);
    }
}
```

It can be done because `dataItem` itself has `Field2`. This will iterate through each element of each group. If you want to show only the keys of the groups then just grab key:

```
foreach (var group in dataItems) 
{
     Console.WriteLine(group.Key.Field2);
}
```